# Git Freezing while pushing

Tags: git, terminal

I am trying to push my commit to the remote. It was working fine before but not now. When I run the command

```
git push origin master:master
```

it's showing the following in the terminal and then nothing happens. I've waited so long time. What I am missing here? I use Terminal in Mac, my remote and local has only one branch.

```
    Counting objects: 986, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (500/500), done.
Writing objects: 100% (507/507), 2.93 MiB | 548 KiB/s, done.
Total 507 (delta 482), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

Comment: What version of git are you using? Is your remote a repo on GitHub or Bitbuket?

Comment: git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37) - This is my git version which comes with my Xcode 4.5. My remote is in my local network.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with an independent distribution of git? (Independent from XCode)

Comment: I tried the same in another machine like you said. Same thing happens there also